# PHP: Use local image if it exsists

Tags: php, image, caching, directory, local

I have a script to cache images locally. It works perfectly;

```
<?
$image = file_get_contents("$bg");
$filename = basename($bg);
file_put_contents("images/$filename", $image);
?>
<img src="<? echo $bg; ?>"><br>
```

However, I want my script to use the local image in the `img` tag if it's already downloaded and present in my folder. If the image isn't already downloaded, then save the external image and then use the local image.

In other words; Check if the image is already in the folder, if it's not - then download it and display the local file. If it's already in the folder, just display the local image without downloading the image again.

Comment: On what basis do you want to check if image is already there in local system? On the basis of image name or the image itself??

Comment: Just on the basis of the image name :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the existance of file with `file_exists` function please see documentation : 
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-exists.php

```
<?php
 $filename = basename($bg);
 if(!file_exists($filename))
 {
    $image = file_get_contents("$bg");
    file_put_contents("images/$filename", $image);
 }
?>
 <img src="images/<?php print $filename?>"><br />
```

Comment: Works as a charm! Can I use the else function here? Like this?
`<?php
  $filename = basename($bg);
  if(!file_exists(images/$filename))
  {
     $image = file_get_contents("$bg");
     file_put_contents("images/$filename", $image);
  $background = "images/$filename";
  } else {
  $background = "images/$filename";
  }
?>`

Comment: You're welcome =) 
yes you can and just print $background variable into src attributes ^^ 
Don't hesitate to try several solutions , it helps you to improve your coding usually tips

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php):

```
<?php
$filename = basename($bg);
if(!file_exists("images/$filename")){
    // we don't have it, Cache it first
    $image = file_get_contents("$bg");
    file_put_contents("images/$filename", $image);
}
?>

<img src="<? echo $bg; ?>"><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file_exists` function to check already exits or not.

Try example

```
<?php
$filename = basename($bg);
if(!file_exists($filename))
{
    $image = file_get_contents("$bg");
    file_put_contents("images/$filename", $image);
}
?>
<img src="images/<?=$filename?>"><br>
```